# Excel- How To Find Multiple Matches of Keywords

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of keywords in column C. I have random strings/sentences in column A.

And column B uses a formula that finds if any cell in Column A contains any of the keywords.

The current formula I use, finds these matches perfectly. (Outputs shown in column B)

However, is there a way to find/concatenate **multiple matches?**. In the screenshot, you can see cell A4 have "Orange Yellow", but cell B4 only prints "Orange" from the formula. Since this cell contains 2 keywords, is there a way to print both?

[image]

current formula used- =XLOOKUP(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C:$C,A1)),$C:$C,"no match",2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FILTER()` and `TEXTJOIN()` together.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTER($C$1:$C$6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$C$6,A1))))
```

[image]